# Facebook access token for public events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am creating event-management website which will in its most basic form list domestic events ordered by cities in which they are happening.

For this website, I wanted to implement feature where anyone who wants to submit their event can easily enter existing Facebook Event ID and then in the backend using Facebook Graph API (PHP SDK) I would pull event info from Facebook and persist in database.

For this purpose I have created Facebook app and received App ID and App Secret. To use Facebook SDK, I am required to obtain Access Token. From what I understand, it would be easily obtained if my users had to authenticate on my website with their Facebook profile. However, I would want this process to be user independent - so that anyone can come and submit their Facebook Event ID.

What are my options to retrieve permanent Access Token which I can use to call Graph API to receive public event data?

NOTE: I will also have Facebook page where I will share some of the events on the wall (not assign them as they are hosted by this page), but I don't believe this should be mixed into above scenario in any way.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every event in Facebook should have particular privacy setting. So for the event that only visible to the user, you can not pull it through graph api unless the user grant permission to your app. If your target events are only the public events, the easiest way could be using your app token to fetch the event by id.

Comment: I didn't know about the App Token which is AppID|AppSecret combination. This is curently my solution because I am interested only in server to server communication with Graph API and only interested in public events.

Comment: Besides AppID|AppSecret combination, you can also use the generated app token which can be find in  "Tools & Support" => "Access Token Tool"